# How to create a template helper pathFor path

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Usually I just do `{{pathFor 'dashboard'}}`

But what if I get the path `'dashboard'` from template helper as `{{name}}`

I can't do this`{{pathFor '{{name}}'}}` but I need to!

It's a submenu which looks like:

```
{{#each connectedChannels}} 
  {{> submenuChannel}} 
{{/each}}

<template name="submenuChannel">
    <li>
      <a href="{{pathFor '{{name}}'}}"><span class="sidebar-text">{{name}}</span></a>
    </li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you remove the quotes and braces around `name`:

```html
<a href="{{pathFor name}}">
```